# Grepping output from JenkinsFile ConsoleText

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to grep some output from a JenkinsFile and assign it a variable.

```
def AMI_ID = sh(script: 'curl https://jenkins-xxxx.com/job/root-image/job/consoleText | grep -o "ami-[0-z]*" | tail -1')
```

```
echo "${AMI_ID}"
```

I ran this locally on my MAC and it returns the output I expect. However I am guessing it may be something with groovy which is causing this to not work as it is returning null.

Also just to note I am using curl here to just grab an old build that has an ami for testing. I ideally want to run a Jenkins job and then grab the AMI id from that current build with something like this curl ${BUILD_URL}consoleText  so maybe there is a better way than using curl.

Answer (score 0):

To assign the output of a shell command, you should use it like this:

```
def dirList = sh script: "ls -lhtr", returnStdout: true
print(dirList)
```

Best regards!